# send email automatically in Microsoft dynamics CRM

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2013, dynamics-crm-online

I have field in entity `Quote` called `new_date_expiration` (type = Date).

I want **send email** if `new_date_expiration` equals date system in Microsoft dynamics CRM **automatically**.

any ideas?

thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you try setting up a wait condition in the workflow and set it to be equal to process execution time? Set up the workflow to run on create.

Comment: What is the idea with the mail? If you have a lot of quotes that will give you a lot of waiting workflows which might be a bad idea.

Comment: yes you right Rickard  ,  do you have any anthor idea

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using the [CRM Workflow Automation Tool](https://workflowautomation.codeplex.com/) combined with an on-demand workflow. The setup process is quite simple:

1. Create a new workflow in CRM (make sure the "run on demand" option is turned on) which generates and sends your email.
2. Create an advanced find query on your entity which defines the criteria of when you want the email to be sent. In your case it sounds like the condition would be something like `Expiration Date [equals] Today`.
3. Once you are satisfied with the advanced find query, copy of the source FetchXML for it.
4. Configure the CRM Workflow Automation Tool (instructions on how to do this are included in the download package) to run the workflow created in the first step using the FetchXML you just copied.
5. Set your server to run the tool run daily at, for example, 8 AM using Windows Task Scheduler.

Once you have this configured, everyday at the specified time the results of the FetchXML query will be pulled and the provided workflow will be run against it. This effectively accomplishes exactly what you want without a bunch of timeouts.